# how to open web application in 2003 server with VS2005 when error csproj is not installed

Tags: asp.net

application for project    .....csproj is not installed. 
Make sure the application for the project type (.csproj) is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're trying to open a `C#` project using a Visual Studio that was installed without that feature.

Try to run Visual Studio Setup again, choose the `Add or Remove Features` option then check the `Visual C#` box.

Answer (score 1):

How to open file X if application for X is not installed? Install [application X](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/).